# swift - how to call uiviewcontroller method in appdelegate

Tags: swift, singleton

webView variable is nil.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

how to using singleton object?

```
class PushHandler: NSObject, UAPushNotificationDelegate {

    func receivedNotificationResponse(_ notificationResponse: UANotificationResponse, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
        print("The user selected the following action identifier:%@", notificationResponse.actionIdentifier);

        if let targetUrl = notificationResponse.notificationContent.notificationInfo["url"] {
            let viewController:MCKWebViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MCKWebViewController") as! MCKWebViewController
            // .instantiatViewControllerWithIdentifier() returns AnyObject! this must be downcast to utilize it

            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            viewController.goURL(targetUrl as! String)
        }
        completionHandler()
}



class MCKWebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    func goURL(_ targetUrl: String) {
        let url = URL(string: targetUrl)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Where did your error occur ?

Comment: webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
webView is nil.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `_ = viewController.view`  after `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method